# Reactjs: br tag and ajax request

Tags: ajax, reactjs

My question is divided into two parts:

1. I know how to do ajax request to third party api on componentDidMount but when i tried doing same request with a function on a click event it did not happen?
2. I also tried to use `<br>` tag in react to break a line but it does not render at a all and gives me error.

Can anyone please help me to understand why this is happening and how can i resolve these issues?

Comment: Can you paste the code? Are there any errors thrown when you click the element? Are you positive the click handler is attaching properly?

Comment: are you sure you used lowercase 'br'?; when you start it with a capital 'B' react thinks it's looking for a component

Answer (score 29):

1. This should work. Please post a working example (e.g., on jsfiddle) that shows how you're having trouble.
2. Try `<br />`. All self-closing tags must have the final slash in React.

(In the future, best to post as separate questions.)